# Recursive fibonacci function that is both the caller and callee (x86 assembly)

Tags: recursion, assembly, x86, calling-convention

I'm trying to write a single recursive function that returns the nth number in the fibonacci sequence (1, 1, 2, 3, 5, ...)

I'm a bit confused since this function is both the caller and the callee in the normal calling convention, and recursive on top of that. My code so far is outputting the input(n) for each case.

```
        push ebp
        mov ebp, esp
        push edx
        push ecx
        push eax
        push ebx
        push esi
        push edi

        //body
        mov ecx, [ebp + 8] // n parameter
        cmp ecx, 2
        jge Else
        mov eax, 1
        jmp Epilouge

    Else:
        //mov edx, ecx // save n
        dec ecx
        push ecx
        call fibonacci
        add esp, 4
        mov ebx, eax // move first returned result into ebx
        sub ecx, 2
        push ecx
        call fibonacci
        add esp, 4
        add eax, ebx // add the two returned values


    Epilouge:
        pop edi
        pop esi
        pop ebx
        pop eax
        pop ecx
        pop edx

        pop ebp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There a couple of issues with your code:

1. You are saving and restoring `eax` in the prologue and in the epilogue.
   Since `eax` is used to return the function value, this effectively prevent your function from returning any value.
2. `sub ecx, 2` should be `sub ecx, 1`.
   Otherwise you compute *f(n) = f(n - 1) + f(n - 3)* which is not the Fibonacci function and which [first values](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f(-1)+%3D+1,+f(0)+%3D+1,+f(1)+%3D+1,+f(n)+%3D+f(n-1)+%2B+f(n-3)) resemble the identity map.

You have been saved by the skin of your teeth by the use of `jge` in place of `jae` (effectively adding the initial condition *f(k) = 1,* ∀*k < 2*) otherwise *f(-1)* would have been treated as *f(2<sup>32</sup>-1)*.

Finally I assume the epilogue is missing

```
ret
```

due to a simple copy-paste error.

Comment: Correct on the copy paste error. I took out the push/pop eax as well as changed sub eax to 1. It worked! Do you mind explaining what jae is and why it was good not to use it?

Comment: @user6313136 `jae` is *Jumb Above Equal*, the *unsigned* version of `jge`. It's not bad but in the original implementation `fibonacci(2) = fibonacci(1) + fibonacci(-1)` and so you had to deal with signed numbers. Using `jge` -1 is not greater equal 2, using `jae` -1 (which is *0ffffffffh* unsigned) is greater equal 2; thereby transforming `fibonacci(-1)` into `fibonacci(0ffffffffh) = fibonacci(4.294.967.295) = fibonacci(2^32-1)`